# Android app to call a predefined number when a specific text is received

Tags: android, automation, sms

I am looking for an app for my Android phone that when it receives a specific text, for example, "call now", it will then call a specific phone number already defined and then will hang up after a second.

Comment: What version  of Android should it work with?

Comment: Android 5 is enough

Answer (score 1):

[Tasker](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.dinglisch.android.taskerm&hl=en) is able to do this and much more. See steps below to achieve your goal:

1. Setup a profile with the "Received Text" Event trigger
2. Set "Type: Any" and Fill in the content with the triggering text. You can add a specific number or set of numbers to the Sender box if you only want specific people to be able to trigger the action.
3. Create a task that makes a call (New Action > Phone > Call), waits (New Action > Task > Wait), and ends the call (New Action > Phone > End Call).
4. Set the profile to trigger the task

Answer (score 1):

Tasker seems to be a bit overkill for this, so I created a simple and free app for this:
[Open Sesame Gate](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.fletech.android.opensesame.gate), it might help others as well.